# How can I scp the contents of a directory to a remote host?

Tags: ssh, scp

I am using the scp command to copy only the contents of a directory to another directory on a remote host. The files and directories in the keys directory need to be copied to the remote hosts keys directory. Using the below command the 'keys' directory gets copied to the "keys" directory on the remote host.

```
scp ${SSH_ARGS} -r keys/* $PATH/keys
```

Comment: Have you tried adding another slash at the end? `scp ${SSH_ARGS} -r keys/* $PATH/keys/`

Comment: Not quite sure that worked. But I did delete the directory that was copied over along with the contents. I think its the -r flag but that is needed when I have sub-directories.